# ¿Como puedo sacar la información de un arreglo en java script?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Tengo la duda de cómo poder sacar la información de un arreglo, ya que al momento de construir el arreglo, después debo hacer una comparación de que si viene ese arreglo sacar la información y meterla en un formulario.

El flujo de mi código para que lo entiendan es: en una tabla se llenan unos campos que están en su celda, pero cuando se llega a un `td` que tiene la función de `onclick`, se abre un modal con un formulario para dar de alta un domicilio, entonces cuando en el modal se le da a *continuar* se genera un arreglo con los datos del domicilio, pero si por cualquier cuestión se equivocan y quieren volver abrir el modal,

1. Es que los datos se vuelvan a ver, los que se escribieron en el formulario (pero como el formulario se construye cuando se abre el modal pues se limpia y necesito que se vea lo que ya se guardó en el arreglo);
2. Es que cuando ya estén los datos correctos se sustituyan los cambios en el arreglo si es que hay.

Ya que al enviar los datos envío 3 arreglos y 1 de ellos es en donde va el domicilio, porque lo mando en arreglo, porque se pueden agregar varias filas en la tabla y cada fila lleva diferentes domicilios.

```js
//FUNCION ABRIR POPUP===============================================================================
  function abrirPopupAltaDomicilioHbb(posiciones){
    posicion = posiciones;

    coordenadasTabla = $(globalClaseAgregarLineaDatosHbb+"[posicion="+posicion+"]").attr("coordenadas");
    modeloModem = $(globalClaseAgregarLineaDatosHbb+"[posicion='"+posicion+"']").attr("modeloModem");

    var iccidHbbPopup = $(globalClaseAgregarLineaIccidHbb).val();
    var msisdnHbbPopup = $(globalClaseAgregarLineaMsisdnHbb).val();
    var selectOfertaHbbPopup = $(globalClaseAgregarLineaOfertaHbb).val();
    var numeroSerieHbbPopup = $(globalClaseAgregarLineaNumeroModemHbb).val();
    var imeiHbbPopup = $(globalClaseAgregarLineaImeiModemHbb).val();

    if(validacionCamposInput(iccidHbbPopup, "numeroIccid", ".textoMensaje", "ICCID FORMATO INCORRECTO.", 0, "ICCID ES OBLOGATORIO.") == false){
      $("#msj").modal("toggle");
      return false;
    }

    if(validacionCamposInput(msisdnHbbPopup, "soloNumeros", ".textoMensaje", "MSISDN FORMATO INCORRECTO.", 0, "MSISDN ES OBLOGATORIO.") == false){
      $("#msj").modal("toggle");
      return false;
    }

    if(validacionCamposSelect(selectOfertaHbbPopup, ".textoMensaje", 0, "SELECCIONA UNA OFERTA DISPONIBLE.") == false){
      $("#msj").modal("toggle");
      return false;
    }

    if(validacionCamposInput(numeroSerieHbbPopup, "soloLetrasYNumeros", ".textoMensaje", "NUMERO DE SERIE FORMATO INCORRECTO.", 0, "NUMERO DE SERIE ES OBLOGATORIO.") == false){
      $("#msj").modal("toggle");
      return false;
    }

    if(validacionCamposInput(imeiHbbPopup, "soloNumeros", ".textoMensaje", "IMEI FORMATO INCORRECTO.", 0, "IMEI ES OBLOGATORIO.") == false){
      $("#msj").modal("toggle");
      return false;
    }

    var htmlFormDomicilio =
    "<div class='colLg12 colMd12 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOff etiquetasForm'>"+
      "<p class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 etiquetaFija centerText'>CALLE</p>"+
      "<input type='text' class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 ' name='calleAltaMsisdnHbb' id='calleAltaMsisdnHbb"+globalAgregarLineaPopup+"' posicion ='"+posicion+"' placeholder='CALLE *'/>"+
    "</div>"+
    "<div class='colLg12 colMd12 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOff etiquetasForm'>"+
      "<p class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 etiquetaFija centerText'>COLONIA</p>"+
      "<input type='text' class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24' name='coloniaAltaMsisdnHbb' id='coloniaAltaMsisdnHbb"+globalAgregarLineaPopup+"' posicion ='"+posicion+"' placeholder='COLONIA *'/>"+
    "</div>"+
    "<div class='colLg08 colMd08 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOff etiquetasForm'>"+
      "<p class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 etiquetaFija centerText'>N. EXTERIOR</p>"+
      "<input type='text' class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24' name='numeroExteriorAltaMsisdnHbb' id='numeroExteriorAltaMsisdnHbb"+globalAgregarLineaPopup+"' posicion ='"+posicion+"' placeholder='NUMERO EXTERIOR *'/>"+
    "</div>"+
    "<div class='colLg08 colMd08 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOff etiquetasForm'>"+
      "<p class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 etiquetaFija centerText'>N. INTERIOR</p>"+
      "<input type='text' class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24' name='numeroInteriorAltaMsisdnHbb' id='numeroInteriorAltaMsisdnHbb"+globalAgregarLineaPopup+"' posicion ='"+posicion+"' placeholder='NUMERO INTERIOR'/>"+
    "</div>"+
    "<div class='colLg08 colMd08 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOff etiquetasForm'>"+
      "<p class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 etiquetaFija centerText'>CP</p>"+
      "<input type='text' class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24' name='codigoPostalAltaMsisdnHbb' id='codigoPostalAltaMsisdnHbb"+globalAgregarLineaPopup+"' posicion ='"+posicion+"' placeholder='CODIGO POSTAL *' maxlength='5'/>"+
    "</div>";
    $(".formDomicilioHbb").html(htmlFormDomicilio);

    $("#popupDomicilioHbb").modal("toggle");
    
  }
  //====================================================================================================

   //FUNCION AGREGAR MSISDN HBB ARRAY=======================================================================
  function clickValidacionesDomicilioHbb(){

    var calleHbb = $("#calleAltaMsisdnHbb"+globalAgregarLineaPopup+""+"[posicion="+posicion+"]").val();
    var coloniaHbb = $("#coloniaAltaMsisdnHbb"+globalAgregarLineaPopup+""+"[posicion="+posicion+"]").val();
    var exteriorHbb = $("#numeroExteriorAltaMsisdnHbb"+globalAgregarLineaPopup+""+"[posicion="+posicion+"]").val();
    var interiorHbb = $("#numeroInteriorAltaMsisdnHbb"+globalAgregarLineaPopup+""+"[posicion="+posicion+"]").val();
    var codigoPostalHbb = $("#codigoPostalAltaMsisdnHbb"+globalAgregarLineaPopup+""+"[posicion="+posicion+"]").val();

    var iccid = $(globalClaseAgregarLineaIccidHbb+"[posicion="+posicion+"]").val();
    var msisdn = $(globalClaseAgregarLineaMsisdnHbb+"[posicion="+posicion+"]").val();
    var oferta = $(globalClaseAgregarLineaOfertaHbb+"[posicion="+posicion+"]").val();
    var numeroModem = $(globalClaseAgregarLineaNumeroModemHbb+"[posicion="+posicion+"]").val();
    var imeiModem = $(globalClaseAgregarLineaImeiModemHbb+"[posicion="+posicion+"]").val();
    // var precioModem = $(globalClaseAgregarLineaPrecioModemHbb+"[posicion="+posicion+"]").val();
    var precioModem = $(globalClaseAgregarLineaDatosHbb+"[posicion="+posicion+"]").attr("precioModemHbb");

    var conceptoOfertaHbb = $(globalClaseAgregarLineaOfertaHbb+"[posicion="+posicion+"] option:selected").attr("descripcion");
    var importeOfertaHbb = $(globalClaseAgregarLineaOfertaHbb+"[posicion="+posicion+"] option:selected").attr("importe");
    var idConcepto = $(globalClaseAgregarLineaOfertaHbb+"[posicion="+posicion+"] option:selected").attr("idConcepto");

    if(validacionCamposInput(calleHbb, "soloLetrasYNumeros", ".textoMensaje", "SOLO RECIBE LETRAS Y/O NÚMEROS.", 0, "CALLE ES OBLOGATORIO.") == false){
      $("#msj").modal("toggle");
      return false;
    }

    if(validacionCamposInput(coloniaHbb, "soloLetrasYNumeros", ".textoMensaje", "SOLO RECIBE LETRAS Y/O NÚMEROS.", 0, "COLONIA ES OBLOGATORIO.") == false){
      $("#msj").modal("toggle");
      return false;
    }

    if(validacionCamposInput(exteriorHbb, "soloLetrasYNumeros", ".textoMensaje", "SOLO RECIBE LETRAS Y/O NÚMEROS.", 0, "NUMERO EXTERIOR ES OBLOGATORIO.") == false){
      $("#msj").modal("toggle");
      return false;
    }

    if(validacionCamposInput(codigoPostalHbb, "soloLetrasYNumeros", ".textoMensaje", "SOLO RECIBE LETRAS Y/O NÚMEROS.", 0, "CODIGO POSTAL ES OBLOGATORIO.") == false){
      $("#msj").modal("toggle");
      return false;
    }

    $(".textoMensaje").text("El domicilio se guardo correctamente.");
    $("#msj").modal("toggle");

    hbbMsisdn = {
      coordenadas: coordenadasTabla,
      iccid: iccid,
      msisdn: msisdn,
      idOferta: oferta,
      idConcepto: idConcepto,
      numeroModem: numeroModem,
      imei: imeiModem,
      precio: precioModem,
      calle: calleHbb,
      colonia: coloniaHbb,
      num_ext: exteriorHbb,
      num_int: interiorHbb,
      cp: codigoPostalHbb,
      costo: importeOfertaHbb
    };
    msisdnHbb.push(hbbMsisdn);

    var htmlPagosHbb = ""+
      "<tr class='resultados agregarPagoHbb"+globalAgregarLineaPopup+"' posicion='"+posicion+"'>"+
        "<td class='resultado agregarHbbMsisdnPago"+globalAgregarLineaPopup+"'>"+msisdn+"</td>"+
        "<td class='resultado'>"+conceptoOfertaHbb+"</td>"+
        "<td class='resultado precioTotalOferta"+globalAgregarLineaPopup+"'>"+importeOfertaHbb+"</td>"+
        "<td class='resultado'>"+imeiModem+"</td>"+
        "<td class='resultado precioTotalModem"+globalAgregarLineaPopup+"'>"+precioModem+"</td>"+
      "</tr>";

   $(globalClaseTablaPagoLineaHbb).append(htmlPagosHbb);

    var domicilioCargado = document.querySelectorAll(globalClaseTablaDomicilioLineaHbb);
    domicilioCargado[contadorPagosAgregarHbb].style.backgroundColor = "#38C659";

    contadorPagosAgregarHbb++;
    resultadoTotalPago();

    $(globalClaseTablaMsisdnsAgregarLineaHbb+" tr"+globalClaseAgregarLineaDatosHbb+""+"[posicion='"+posicion+"']").each(function(){
      var idMsisdnHbb        = $(this).attr("idMsisdnHbb");
      var idConceptoModemHbb = $(this).attr("idConceptoEquipo");
      var idModemHbb         = $(this).attr("idModemHbb");


      var tempConceptosCobroMsisdnHbb = {
        "idConcepto": idConcepto,
        "importe": importeOfertaHbb,
        "detalles": "ACTIVACION HBB",
        "tipoEquipo": "MSISDN",
        "idEquipo": idMsisdnHbb
      }

      var tempConceptosCobroModemHbb = {
        "idConcepto": idConceptoModemHbb,
        "importe": precioModem,
        "detalles": "EQUIPO HBB",
        "tipoEquipo": "EQUIPOHBB",
        "idEquipo": idModemHbb
      }

      conceptosCobro.push(tempConceptosCobroMsisdnHbb, tempConceptosCobroModemHbb);
    });

    var importeTotalOfertaHbb = parseFloat(importeOfertaHbb);

    conceptoOfertaHbb = conceptoOfertaHbb.split("(");

    conceptoOfertaHbb = conceptoOfertaHbb[0]+" ("+msisdn+")";
    importeTotalOfertaHbb = importeTotalOfertaHbb * 100;

    var tempConceptosCobroConektaOferta = {
      "name": conceptoOfertaHbb,
      "unit_price": importeTotalOfertaHbb,
      "quantity": 1
    }

    var importeTotalModemHbb = parseFloat(precioModem);

    var modem = "MODEM "+modeloModem+" ("+msisdn+")";
    importeTotalModemHbb = importeTotalModemHbb * 100;

    var tempConceptosCobroConektaModem = {
      "name": modem,
      "unit_price": importeTotalModemHbb,
      "quantity": 1
    }

    conceptosCobroHbbConekta.push(tempConceptosCobroConektaOferta, tempConceptosCobroConektaModem);

    $(".closeFormDomicilioHbb").click();
  }
  //====================================================================================================
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="popupDomicilioHbb" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modalDialog modalColLg12 modalColMd12 modalColSm12" role="document">
    <div class="modalContent">
      <div class="modalHeader">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modalTitle">ALTA DOMICILIO HBB</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modalBody">
        <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 form">
          <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 cuerpoForm formDomicilioHbb"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clear">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modalFooter clear">
      <div type='button' class='popupBtnCerrar closeFormDomicilioHbb' data-dismiss='modal'><div class='cancelar'></div>Cancelar</div>
      <div type='button' class='popupBtnConfirmar' onClick='clickValidacionesDomicilioHbb(this);'><div class='continuar'></div>Continuar</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No olvides agregar la versión de jQuery en el snippet (en _Añadir librería externa_).

Comment: @David081 una parte si, pero la otra es sacar la info de un arreglo y despues sustituir esos datos al arreglo.

Comment: Si le colocas la propiedad `data-keyboard` con valor boolean = `false`, en tu modal evitara que se cierre con un click fuera del modal: `<div class="modal fade" id="popupDomicilioHbb" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-keyboard=false aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">`